# What is the best way to develop a web app cross frameworks

Tags: html, reactjs, web, frontend

We are trying to develop a web app overlay kind of thing that pops up like a chatbot from the bottom of the page and currently coding it in react. We want this to be easily integratable to our customer companies' websites even if they don't use react but use vanilla html, asp etc.

What would be the best way to achieve this flexibility

Comment: by not using frameworks the require special dependencies.

Comment: @tacoshy, would that mean using vanilla html-css? What exactly do you mean by special dependencies? I noticed that Flutter builds are only in JS, HTML, and CSS. Can I use Flutter then?

Comment: React is Node.js based as such you have a dependency on Node.js. Bootstrap 5 as an example gives you a vanilla CSS file. You're not dependent on jQuery or SASS. You could work with Bootstrap-5 without issue. Flutter will not work as it is not JS but Dart and C++.

Comment: @tacoshy, thank you for your explanation. Turns out the Flutter team just released support for this as of May 10 2023. So that is what I am gonna go with at least initially. For anyone interested, see this https://github.com/flutter/samples/tree/main/web_embedding/element_embedding_demo